# Extending pandas data frame using date time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` as follows:

```
1/25/2001   1364.3  1367.35 1354.63
1/24/2001   1360.4  1369.75 1357.28
1/23/2001   1342.9  1362.9  1339.63
```

I want to extend it as `res` follows:

```
1/26/2001   NaN     NaN     NaN
1/25/2001   1364.3  1367.35 1354.63
1/24/2001   1360.4  1369.75 1357.28
1/23/2001   1342.9  1362.9  1339.63
1/22/2001   NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I tried as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fi, header=None, sep=',')
print (df)
index = np.arange(np.datetime64('2001-01-22'), np.datetime64('2001-01-27'))
print (index)
res = df.reindex(index).iloc[::-1]
print (res)

              0   1   2   3
2001-01-26  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2001-01-25  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2001-01-24  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2001-01-23  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2001-01-22  NaN NaN NaN NaN


res = pd.DataFrame(df, index=index)
print (res)
```

It also prints same as above.
How to obtain expected res?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work:

```
In [89]: df
Out[89]: 
           0       1        2        3
0 2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
1 2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
2 2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63

In [90]: df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
In [91]: index = np.arange(np.datetime64('2001-01-22'), np.datetime64('2001-01-27'))

In [92]: index
Out[92]: array(['2001-01-22', '2001-01-23', '2001-01-24', '2001-01-25', '2001-01-26'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [106]: df
Out[106]: 
                 1        2        3
0                                   
2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63

In [107]: df.reindex(index)
Out[107]: 
                 1        2        3
0                                   
2001-01-22     NaN      NaN      NaN
2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63
2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
2001-01-26     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

or hard way:

```
In [94]: pd.concat([df,pd.Series(index)]).drop_duplicates(0).sort_values(0)
Out[94]: 
           0       1        2        3
0 2001-01-22     NaN      NaN      NaN
2 2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63
1 2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
0 2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
4 2001-01-26     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

Comment: i have updated the answer convert your time column to datetime type

Comment: yes, it worked +1, but looking for more better, straight ways, if any...

Comment: u need to convert your time column to datetime type as shown in line 90.

Comment: i did that , but no success

Comment: try this while reading the file in dataframe as `pd.read_csv(fil,parse_date=[Time_Column_Name],infer_datetime_format=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `reindex`

```
index = np.arange(np.datetime64('2001-1-22'), np.datetime64('2001-1-26'))

df=df.reindex(index).iloc[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fine, only is necessaty convert index to `DatetimeIndex` - by `parse_date=True` and `index_col=[0]` in `read_csv` or `pd.DatetimeIndex` or `pd.to_datetime(df.index)`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fi, header=None, parse_date=True, index_col=[0])
print (df)
                 1        2        3
0                                   
2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-25', '2001-01-24', '2001-01-23'], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=0, freq=None)

index = np.arange(np.datetime64('2001-01-22'), np.datetime64('2001-01-27'))

#df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
#alternatvie
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
res = df.reindex(index).iloc[::-1]
print (res)
                 1        2        3
0                                   
2001-01-26     NaN      NaN      NaN
2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63
2001-01-22     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

If want expand datetimes more dynamic by max and min dates is possible add `Timedelta`s and change order:

```
index = pd.date_range(df.index.min() - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'), 
                      df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))[::-1]

res = df.reindex(index)
print (res)
                 1        2        3
2001-01-26     NaN      NaN      NaN
2001-01-25  1364.3  1367.35  1354.63
2001-01-24  1360.4  1369.75  1357.28
2001-01-23  1342.9  1362.90  1339.63
2001-01-22     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: If not datetimeindex, try `df = pd.read_csv(fi, header=None, parse_date=True, index_col=[0])`

Comment: print (df.index); all nan

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

Comment: OK, so need add 2 parameters to read_csv - `parse_date=True, index_col=[0]` - first convert index to datetimeindex and second set first column to index.